# How to assign value to undefined

Tags: javascript, module, undefined

Todd mentioned in [his article](https://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/) that it is possible to assign a value of undefined(as a reason to put the object into arguments without assigning it):

> In ECMAScript 3, undefined is mutable. Which means its value could be
>   reassigned, something like undefined = true; for instance, oh my!
>   Thankfully in ECMAScript 5 strict mode ('use strict';) the parser will
>   throw an error telling you you’re an idiot. Before this, we started
>   protecting our IIFE’s by doing this:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {

})(window, document);
```

> Which means if someone came along and did this, we’d be okay:

```
undefined = true;
(function (window, document, undefined) {
    // undefined is a local undefined variable
})(window, document);
```

However, I tried to assign it without any luck:

```
$ undefined = true
$ true
$ undefined
$ undefined
```

Can anyone say how to do that? Just out of curiosity. Or new browsers dont allow this anymore?

Comment: Why would you want to, seems like an awful waste of time and energy? :/

Comment: The only way I found to assign value to `undefined` is using closure `(function(undefined){ console.log("\"Undefined\" parametter:", undefined);})("test")` the `undefined` variable inside the function will contain the string `test`.

Comment: @Filipe ha! it really works! thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting as an answer:

```
(function(undefined){

    console.log("\"undefined\" parameter:", undefined);

})("test");
```

It will work.